# отправка данных через ик-свветодиод к приёмнику

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, gpio

Всем привет.
Мне нужно реализовать передачу небольших пакетов данных через ик-светодиод к ик-приёмнику. С приёмом данных вроде как всё более-менее понятно, а вот с передачей (структурированных пакетов данных) разобраться не могу, прошу совета.